# How to determine if the limit of this infinite nested radical is an algebraic or transcendental number

Tags: abstract-algebra, complex-analysis, polynomials, algebraic-number-theory

> **Theorem:** For $0<p<1$ and $a_n\ge 0$, the limit
>   $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} a_1+(a_2+(\cdots+(a_n)^p)^p)^p$$
>   exists if and only if the sequence $(a_n^{p^n})_n$ is bounded.

How to determine if this limit is a transcendental number or algebraic number?